# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected flatten_input to have 3 dimensions, but got array with shape (50000, 32, 32, 3)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, mnist

I just started using Tensorflow and I kind of got an error.

```
cifar10_mnist = keras.datasets.cifar10

(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = cifar10_mnist.load_data()

train_images = train_images/255
test_images = test_images/255
classes = ['airplane', 'automobile', 'bird', 'cat', 'deer', 'dog', 'frog', 'horse', 'ship', 
'truck']

model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(32,32)),
    keras.layers.Dense(150, activation="relu"),
    keras.layers.Dense(10, activation="softmax")
])
model.compile(optimizer="adam", loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=5)

test_loss, test_acc = model.evaluate(test_images, test_labels)

prediction = model.predict(test_images)
answer = np.argmax(prediction[0])
print(classes[answer])
```

I'm not really sure how to go about this, I've been looking back but I don't see anything I can change to fix this. Thank you, really appreciate the help. :)

Comment: The input shape to your first layer is `(32, 32, 3)`, not `(32, 32)`.

Comment: Hi Kris, where are you seeing this?

Comment: Thank you, this fixed my problem, appreciate it. However, would you mind replying where you saw that it was (32, 32,3)?

Comment: It's in the error message (title of your question). The input shape is `(batch_size, height, width, channels) = (50000, 32, 32, 3)`